# Create a Hoverable 3rd Level Dropdown in Bootstrap Nav Menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

New to this, trying to learn bootstrap and I am literally hitting my head on the wall already. I have a navigation menu...with a dropdown menu that works on hover. Now what I want to do is create a further sub-menu (Level 3) that also works on hover. Much like a 3rd level nested menu. Hover on "menu 1" and "Menu 2" appears, Hover on Menu 2 and "Menu 3" appears...all fully nested. I can't seem to get it to work. Would be eternally grateful if someone can put me in the right direction.

```css
.navbar-brand {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 900;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.navbar-nav {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: -1px;
  min-width: 250px;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #ff4444;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu>li>a {
  padding: 8px 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu>li:hover>a,
.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu>li:focus>a,
.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu>li.active>a {
  background-color: #7f2222;
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu>li:last-child>a {
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}

.dropdown-menu>li.divider {
  background-color: transparent;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
      <!-- navbar-brand is hidden on larger screens, but visible when the menu is collapsed -->
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index">XYZ Company</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><b>Level 1</b>
                                <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="level2">Level 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="level2">Level 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="level2">Level 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="level2">Level 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="level2">Level 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="level2">Level 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is, I want to add a third level dropdown list and i do not know the steps to take. I am fairly new at this.